# Azure databricks cluster error in a spark job : ExecutorLostFailure

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I was trying to train an xgboost model in pysaprk on Azure Databricks, this code was executing completely fine till yesterday but now I am getting this error:

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 107 in stage 29437.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 107.3 in stage 29437.0 (TID 7682534, 10.139.64.64, executor 145): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 145 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 163728 ms

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the parameter value of `spark.network.timeout`.

```
spark-submit --conf spark.network.timeout 10000000 ......
```

Refer to [spark.network.timeout](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking)

Comment: I tried to increase the parameter value of spark.network.timeout. 
 spark.conf.set("spark.network.timeout", 10000000)                                                             but it got this : Cannot modify the value of a Spark config: spark.network.timeout

Comment: You need to specify this parameter when creating ```spark session``` instead of modifying it after creation.

Comment: Can it be done via notebook because I dont have the permission to change cluster configurations

Comment: I suggest you refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure. See the chapter ```Spark configuration```.